# Batch dust ETH from multiple private keys / wallets together as one transaction?

Tags: metamask, wallets

I use metamask and have many accounts that have small amounts of ETH and other ERC20 tokens. Some accounts have $5-$20 worth of USDC or ETH and I want to make a batch transaction to send all these dust amounts into one account. Is there such a tool or way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with Ethereum protocol because each account would have to sign a transaction to authorize the movement of the funds.

Hope it helps.